# Manage multiple progress view in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uiprogressview

i have a table where in each dynamic cell there is a label with a URL and a progress view. How can i use the progress view to show the progress of each download from the URL of each cell??

Comment: i am unable to get your full requirement bcz of lack of information but with my assumption you can manage it by giving a tag to each progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the request objects in an array and then just setup a progress bar in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method based on its respective request.  This approach is better as opposed to storing the progress bars themselves as table cells and the views inside of them should be reused.

Comment: Does it cover the use case if user goes to some other screen or say pops the viewcontroller and then pushes again with different data and again pops it and comes back to load the data for which progressview is being used?